# import .csv file in R containing strings and numerics how to convert?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a .csv file and imported it in R:

```
    X        A       B       C 
1           good    luck    man
2 string1            
3 string2   2.2     3.3     4
4 string3   0.1     10      3
```

I used:

```
read.csv("~/Desktop/test.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This is of class `data.frame`. Now I delete the first row and set the first column as rownames

```
test <- test[-1,]
rownames(test) <- test[,1]
test <- test[,-1]
```

This gives

```
> test
          A   B C
string1          
string2 2.2 3.3 4
string3 0.1  10 3
```

The problem is, all the values are of class character. I would like to change them to numeric and convert the empty "cells" (i.e. empty strings "") to NA but still having a data.frame. How can this be achieved?

Comment: (Untested) `test[] <- sapply(test, as.numeric)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg No, this gives again a matrix and the rownames are deleted therefore. Obviously I could first generate a matrix, then convert it back. I'm wondering if there is no shorter solution

Comment: That doesn't give a matrix. Did you forget to add `[]` after `test`? Please copy paste the code as is

Comment: @akrun then I get a list

Comment: Please do `test[] <- sapply(test, as.numeric)` , **not**  `a[] <- sapply(test,as.numeric)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ah, I see my mistake. Can you explain why this works? If you wirte an answer I will accept it. Many thanks!

Comment: @user8, because `[]` preserves the `test` data set class, while `a` is undefined. If you want to modify `a`, you should do `a <- test ; a[] <- sapply(a, as.numeric)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a good duplicate, so here goes. Use `[]` in order to preserve the class of `test` in combination with `sapply` which by default operates over columns of the data frame (or the arguments, as `data.frame` is essentially a list with columns as its arguments)

```
test[] <- lapply(test, as.numeric)
```

Note: Make sure that non of your columns is of class `factor`, otherwise this will return wrong results (without triggering a warning)

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that your CSV has two heading lines, and you want to use the first as column names?

Read in, skipping both header lines with `skip=2` and (probably) `head=FALSE` in `read.csv`.

Then you have a data frame with generic column names but correct types.

Then read the second line of the file again, using `readLines`, and split that to get column names for the data frame you read in.

```
> df = read.csv("twohead.txt",skip=2,head=FALSE)
> colnames(df)=strsplit(readLines("twohead.txt",n=2)[2],",")[[1]]
> df
          good luck man
1 string1   NA   NA  NA
2 string2  1.2  1.1 2.2
3 string3  1.5  3.2 1.2
```

Rowname processing is as you have it, although I'd do:

```
> rownames(df)=df[,1]
> df[[1]]=NULL
```

Giving a df:

```
> summary(df)
      good            luck            man      
 Min.   :1.200   Min.   :1.100   Min.   :1.20  
 1st Qu.:1.275   1st Qu.:1.625   1st Qu.:1.45  
 Median :1.350   Median :2.150   Median :1.70  
 Mean   :1.350   Mean   :2.150   Mean   :1.70  
 3rd Qu.:1.425   3rd Qu.:2.675   3rd Qu.:1.95  
 Max.   :1.500   Max.   :3.200   Max.   :2.20  
 NA's   :1       NA's   :1       NA's   :1
```